# Package diagbox ruins my \hline

Tags: tables, cell, diagbox

Preamble:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a4paper, total={190mm, 280mm}]{geometry}

% Greek
\usepackage[LGR, T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek]{babel}
\usepackage{alphabeta}

% Images
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }

% Math
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}

% Dashed Line
\usepackage{arydshln}


\usepackage{diagbox}
```

Document:

```
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\def\arraystretch{1.5}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0.05\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
$\text{Α}_2\text{Α}_1\char`\\ \text{Β}_2\text{Β}_1$
   & 00  & 01  & 10  & 11  \\ \hline
00 & 000 & 001 & 010 & 011 \\ \hdashline
01 & 001 & 010 & 011 & 100 \\ \hdashline
10 & 010 & 011 & 100 & 101 \\ \hdashline
11 & 011 & 100 & 101 & 110 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption*{Table 3}
\end{table}
```

I want to split the top left cell (`$\text{Α}_2\text{Α}_1\char`\ \text{Β}_2\text{Β}_1$`) in to triangles with a diagonal. When I use the diagbox package, my tables appears without the \hline. Why?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) With the information you provided sor far, I can't reproduce the issie you describe. Please prepare a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows how you tried to use the `diagbox` package and add it to your question.

Comment: i just used the command `\usepackage{diagbox}` and nothing else. When I compile i get this error
"The compiler is having trouble understanding a command you have used. Check that the command is spelled correctly. If the command is part of a package, make sure you have included the package in your preamble using \usepackage{...}."

Comment: As soon as you get an error message, do not look at the output, but try to fix the error message first. Which command exactly does the error message you quote in your previous comment refer to? Also, which other packages do you load in your preamble? A compilable example code that allows others to reproduce the output/error messages you get would really help here.

Comment: I updated the question above with the preamble

Comment: Load the `diagbox` package before the `arydshln` package.

Comment: It worked. Can you explain why does this work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124292/discussion-between-leech-and-leandriis).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use `diagbox` and `arydshln`, make sure to load `diagbox` first:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{arydshln}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\def\arraystretch{1.5}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0.05\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\diagbox{$\text{Α}_2\text{Α}_1$}{$\text{Β}_2\text{Β}_1$}
   & 00  & 01  & 10  & 11  \\ \hline
00 & 000 & 001 & 010 & 011 \\ \hdashline
01 & 001 & 010 & 011 & 100 \\ \hdashline
10 & 010 & 011 & 100 & 101 \\ \hdashline
11 & 011 & 100 & 101 & 110 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}    
\end{document}
```

As an alternative, you could also try the `nicematrix` package which comes with its own commands for diagonally split cells and dashed lines. (Compile multiple times to see the final result.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\def\arraystretch{1.5}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0.05\textwidth}
\begin{NiceTabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\diagbox{$\text{Α}_2\text{Α}_1$}{$\text{Β}_2\text{Β}_1$}
   & 00  & 01  & 10  & 11  \\ \hline
00 & 000 & 001 & 010 & 011 \\ \hdashline
01 & 001 & 010 & 011 & 100 \\ \hdashline
10 & 010 & 011 & 100 & 101 \\ \hdashline
11 & 011 & 100 & 101 & 110 \\ \hline
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

That environment has its own built-in command `\diagbox` and tools to draw dashed rules.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\def\arraystretch{1.5}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0.05\textwidth}
\begin{NiceTabular}{ccccc}[vlines]
\Hline
\diagbox{$\text{A}_2\text{A}_1$}{$\text{B}_2\text{B}_1$}
   & 00  & 01  & 10  & 11  \\ \Hline
00 & 000 & 001 & 010 & 011 \\ \Hline[tikz=dashed]
01 & 001 & 010 & 011 & 100 \\ \Hline[tikz=dashed]
10 & 010 & 011 & 100 & 101 \\ \Hline[tikz=dashed]
11 & 011 & 100 & 101 & 110 \\ \Hline
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}    
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]